# Tabs in Tab Bar Controller are disabled and cannot able to switch between the tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on a e-commerce project which has a requirement of having both TabBar and Navigation slider in the application. I have managed to achieve both functionality, but when the app Launches only one tab (Default Home tab) is selected until i navigation to next screens from home tab and come back to home screen i cannot able to switch to the other tabs first time.

Here is the Hierarchy of view controller i have made.

-> Base View controller -> Tab bar and Navigation Sliders (as Childe View controllers)

TabBarController hierarchy :
TabBarController -> NavigationController 1 -> View Controller like this i have 5 tabs with the above combination.

Someone please help me to come out form this issue.

[image: First Launch Screen]

I can't able to tab any tabs in the screen until i tab any one of the cells in this screen.

Below is the code i am using to set the Navigation slider and tab bar controller respectively.

```
///Controller to display Menu Slider
fileprivate var masterViewController: MyMenuTableViewController? {
    willSet {
        if self.masterViewController != nil {
            self.masterViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.masterViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
    } didSet {
        if self.masterViewController != nil {
            self.view.addSubview(self.masterViewController!.view)
            self.addChildViewController(self.masterViewController!)
        }
    }
}

///To display TaBar Controller
fileprivate var detailViewController: HomeViewController? {
    willSet {
        if self.detailViewController != nil {
            self.detailViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.detailViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
    } didSet {
        if self.detailViewController != nil {
            self.view.addSubview(self.detailViewController!.view)
            self.addChildViewController(self.detailViewController!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you could share the code or storyboard on your UI structure (hierarchy)

Comment: your question is not clear @ramprasad. Please share some code.

Comment: @ Hafiz and Maddy: Thanks for the replay. 
The problem i am currently facing is, when the app is launched the others Tabs as given in the Image [eg: My Wishlist, Contact us, Cart and Profile] tabs are not disabled. I cannot able to select any of these until i tap some tableView cells like Book by category or any other.. Once after coming back form those screens the tabs are enabled. This is the issue. Hope u got.

Comment: Please show some code so we can try to help.